# How to conditionally animate with styled-components

Tags: styled-components

I'm trying to animate a line when an input is checked with styled-components.

I've tried with (a) and without (b) keyframes, and both return (c):

```
(a)

import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const Input = styled.input``

const NavIconLine = styled.span`
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
`;

const Animation = keyframes`
    from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    width: 70%;
    }

    to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 100%;
    }
`;

const NavIconLine2 = styled(NavIconLine)`
  width: 70%;

  ${Input}:checked ~ & {
    animation: ${Animation} 0.15s ease-in-out;
  }
`;
```

```
(b)

import styled from 'styled-components';

const Input = styled.input``

const NavIconLine = styled.span`
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
`;

const NavIconLine2 = styled(NavIconLine)`
  width: 70%;

  ${Input}:checked ~ & {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
```

```
(c)

function Component {
  return (
    <Input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
    <NavIcon for="menu">
      <NavIconLine1 />
    </NavIcon>
  )
}
```

I think that perhaps the issue is with the targeting of the element in "${Input}:checked ~ & {...}" as "~ &" refers to the sibling and not the parent's sibling? If that's the case, is possible to target it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Instad of writing the condition on the descendant, it's written on the parent's sibling:

```
const Input = styled.input`
  display: whatever;

  :checked + ${NavIcon} {
    ${NavIconLine1} {
      animation: whatever;
    }
  }
`;
```